# Устранение перебега при притяжении объектов

Tags: unity3d, физика

Объект притягивается к точке в пространстве, но при достижении этой точки, пролетает дальше и происходят незатухающие колебания.
Пользоваться transform или полностью обнулять velosity у объекта я не могу, так как позже объект должен среагировать на столкновение с другим объектом.
Как сделать чтобы объект приближался к точке и останавливался с минимумом колебаний?

Comment: А как именно реализовано передвижение - мы должны угадывать?

Comment: Сделать ПИД-регулятор, меняющий силу притяжения, если это возможно.